# AssetParameters changes when CDK codes updates for EKS deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

CDK is used to deploy EKS in our company. A co-worker created a EKS cluster with CDK and then I pulled the CDK codes, modified something. Before deployment, I ran 'cdk diff' command and the result was shown many resources would be changed. Changes excluded what I modified were all AssetParameters as below.

```
# cdk diff
Stack eks-cluster
Parameters
[-] Parameter AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: {"Type":"String","Description":"S3 bucket for asset \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""}
[-] Parameter AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: {"Type":"String","Description":"S3 key for asset version \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""}
...
[+] Parameter AssetParameters/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/S3Bucket AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: {"Type":"String","Description":"S3 bucket for asset \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""}
[+] Parameter AssetParameters/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/S3VersionKey AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: {"Type":"String","Description":"S3 key for asset version \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""}
...
Resources
[~] AWS::CloudFormation::Stack @aws-cdk--aws-eks.ClusterResourceProvider.NestedStack/@aws-cdk--aws-eks.ClusterResourceProvider.NestedStackResource awscdkawseksClusterResourceProviderNestedStackawscdkawseksClusterResourceProviderNestedStackResourcexxxxx
  [~] TemplateURL
      [~] .Fn::Join:
          @@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
            [ ] },
            [ ] "/",
            [ ] {
            [-]   "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [+]   "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [ ] },
            [ ] "/",
            [ ] {
            @@ -17,7 +17,7 @@
            [ ]   "Fn::Split": [
            [ ]     "||",
            [ ]     {
            [-]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [+]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [ ]     }
            [ ]   ]
            [ ] }
            @@ -30,7 +30,7 @@
            [ ]   "Fn::Split": [
            [ ]     "||",
            [ ]     {
            [-]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [+]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [ ]     }
            [ ]   ]
            [ ] }
[~] AWS::CloudFormation::Stack @aws-cdk--aws-eks.KubectlProvider.NestedStack/@aws-cdk--aws-eks.KubectlProvider.NestedStackResource awscdkawseksKubectlProviderNestedStackawscdkawseksKubectlProviderNestedStackResourcexxxxx
  [~] Parameters
  [+] Added: .referencetoeksclustereksAssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRef
  [+] Added: .referencetoeksclustereksAssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRef
  [-] Removed: .referencetoeksclustereksAssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRef
  [-] Removed: .referencetoeksclustereksAssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxRef
...
  [~] TemplateURL
     [~] .Fn::Join:
         @@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
            [ ] },
            [ ] "/",
            [ ] {
            [-]   "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [+]   "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [ ] },
            [ ] "/",
            [ ] {
            @@ -17,7 +17,7 @@
            [ ]   "Fn::Split": [
            [ ]     "||",
            [ ]     {
            [-]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [+]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [ ]     }
            [ ]   ]
            [ ] }
            @@ -30,7 +30,7 @@
            [ ]   "Fn::Split": [
            [ ]     "||",
            [ ]     {
            [-]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [+]       "Ref": "AssetParametersxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [ ]     }
            [ ]   ]
            [ ] }
```

When the codes is deployed, is there no impact on the EKS cluster in running?

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue this can happen, when the node version differs between machines:

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12427

Comment: Thank you. I asked to AWS support if this issue could affect an existing cluster and then they answered no.